# VBA regex limit to single character

Tags: regex, vba

I have a string where I'd like to match on a VBA regex when there is one intervening parenthesis, but not two.

For example, "desert (cake, pie)" should match, but "desert (pumpkin, sweets(cake, pie))" shouldn't match.

However, this pattern matches both of the above search strings:

```
   regex.Pattern = LCase("desert") & ".*\(.*" & searchString
```

Is there a way to tell it I only one exactly one match, and if there are two, then it's no good?  I think the problem is the .* is gobbling up the second one.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your example correctly, then you can use a simple [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) to achieve this.

```
[^()]*\([^()]*\)
```

=>

```
regex.Pattern = LCase("desert") & [^()]*\([^()]*\) & searchString
```

...would look for an opening paren, followed by any number non-paren characters, followed by a closing paren. Since the pattern is looking for non-paren characters in the middle, your requirement should be satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you just have to tell it to **not** match opening parenthesis after the first one:

```
regex.Pattern = LCase("desert") & ".*\([^\(]*" & searchString
```